# With javascript, please tell me how to get result array like below "resultList". It is similar to the UPDATE statement in SQL

Tags: javascript, arrays

With javascript, please tell me how to get result array like below "resultList".  It is similar to the UPDATE statement in SQL.

```
const dataList = [
  { id: 1, xpstn: "10", ypstn: "11", value:{1,2,3,4}},
  { id: 2, xpstn: "20", ypstn: "21", value:{1,2,3,4}},
  { id: 3, xpstn: "30", ypstn: "31", value:{1,2,3,4}},
  { id: 4, xpstn: "40", ypstn: "41", value:{1,2,3,4}},
     ]
 const paramsList = [
  { id: 3, xpstn: "33", ypstn: "32", desc: "param"},
  { id: 4, xpstn: "44", ypstn: "42", desc: "param"},
  { id: 5, xpstn: "55", ypstn: "53", desc: "param"},
  { id: 6, xpstn: "66", ypstn: "62", desc: "param"},
];


let resultList = [
  { id: 3, xpstn: "33", ypstn: "11", value:{1,2,3,4}},
  { id: 4, xpstn: "44", ypstn: "21", value:{1,2,3,4}},
];
```

The condition is that the id is the same, and xpstn must be updated.

```
UPDATE X
SET X.xpstn = Y.xpstn
FROM dataList X
INNER JOIN paramsList Y  
ON X.id = Y.id
```

Comment: Maybe show (or paraphrase) the SQL UPDATE statement you're trying to mimic?

Comment: UPDATE X
SET X.xpstn = Y.xpstn
FROM dataList X
INNER JOIN paramsList Y  
ON X.id = Y.id

Answer (score 0):

hope this works for you.

```js
const dataList = [
    { id: 1, xpstn: "10", ypstn: "11", value: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
    { id: 2, xpstn: "20", ypstn: "21", value: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
    { id: 3, xpstn: "30", ypstn: "31", value: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
    { id: 4, xpstn: "40", ypstn: "41", value: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
]
const paramsList = [
    { id: 3, xpstn: "33", ypstn: "32", desc: "param" },
    { id: 4, xpstn: "44", ypstn: "42", desc: "param" },
    { id: 5, xpstn: "55", ypstn: "53", desc: "param" },
    { id: 6, xpstn: "66", ypstn: "62", desc: "param" },
];


let resultList = [
    { id: 3, xpstn: "33", ypstn: "31", value: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
    { id: 4, xpstn: "44", ypstn: "41", value: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
];

/*
UPDATE X
SET X.xpstn = Y.xpstn
FROM dataList X
INNER JOIN paramsList Y  
ON X.id = Y.id
*/

const update = (data = [], params = []) => {
    resultList = [];
    data = data.forEach(d => {
        if (params.some(p => p.id === d.id)) {
            r = {
                ...d,
                xpstn: params.find(p => p.id === d.id).xpstn
            }
            resultList.push(r);
        }
    });
    return resultList;
}

console.log("result", update(dataList, paramsList));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with reduce:

```js
const dataList = [{ id: 1, xpstn: "10", ypstn: "11", value: [1, 2, 3, 4] },{ id: 2, xpstn: "20", ypstn: "21", value: [1, 2, 3, 4] },{ id: 3, xpstn: "30", ypstn: "31", value: [1, 2, 3, 4] },{ id: 4, xpstn: "40", ypstn: "41", value: [1, 2, 3, 4] }];
const paramsList = [{ id: 3, xpstn: "33", ypstn: "32", desc: "param" },{ id: 4, xpstn: "44", ypstn: "42", desc: "param" },{ id: 5, xpstn: "55", ypstn: "53", desc: "param" },{ id: 6, xpstn: "66", ypstn: "62", desc: "param" }];

const resultList = dataList.reduce((acc, dataItem) => {
    const paramItem = paramsList.find(({ id }) => id === dataItem.id);
    if (paramItem) {
        const { xpstn } = paramItem;
        acc.push({ ...dataItem,  xpstn });
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(resultList)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```